# Extract the processing of the nc files： IndexError IndexError index 10933172 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 9098798

Tags: python-3.x

```
import pandas as pd
import netCDF4 as nc
for day_num in range(1, 2):
    if day_num < 10:
        file_path = r'F:\desktop\datebase\Carbon-emission-data\AK\Vulcan.v3.AK.hourly.1km.total.mn.2010.d00' + str(
            day_num) + '.nc4'
    else:
        file_path = r'F:\desktop\datebase\Carbon-emission-data\AK\Vulcan.v3.AK.hourly.1km.total.mn.2010.d0' + str(
            day_num) + '.nc4'
    print(f"{file_path}")
    file_obj = nc.Dataset(file_path)
    lon_data = file_obj.variables['lon'][:]
    lat_data = file_obj.variables['lat'][:]
    data_all = None
    try:
        for hours in range(24):
            air = file_obj.variables['carbon_emissions'][hours:hours + 1]
            data = air.data
            data = data[0, :, :]
            data[data == -9999] = 0
            if data_all is None:
                data_all = data
            else:
                data_all += data
        time = file_obj.variables['time']
        y_m_r = nc.num2date(time[:], time.units)
        dt_str = y_m_r[0].strftime("%Y%m%d")
        lon_list = []
        lat_list = []
        data_list = []
        for i in range(data_all.shape[0]):
            for j in range(data_all.shape[1]):
                # print(f"i: {i}, j: {j}")
                    lon_list.append(lon_data[i, j])
                    lat_list.append(lat_data[i, j])
                    data_list.append(data_all[i, j])
        
        df = pd.DataFrame({
            'Longitude': lon_list,
            'Latitude': lat_list,
            'Carbon Emissions': data_list
        })
       
        df_pivot = df.pivot(index='Latitude', columns='Longitude', values='Carbon Emissions')
        out_file_name = 'D:\Python Project\Project2\date_bag\\test\\test2\\' + dt_str + '.csv'
        df.to_csv(path_or_buf=out_file_name)
        print(f"{out_file_name}")
    except IndexError:
        print(f"IndexError at i={i}, j={j}")
        print(f"data_all[{i}, {j}] = {data_all[i, j]}")
        print(f"lon_data[{i}, {j}] = {lon_data[i, j]}")
        print(f"lat_data[{i}, {j}] = {lat_data[i, j]}")
        print(f"data_all.shape={data_all.shape}, lon_data.shape={lon_data.shape}, lat_data.shape={lat_data.shape}")
print("over")
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.